# Facebook Like Box HTML5 not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, twitter

The Facebook Like Box doesn't work when I use the HTML5 code and I can't use the iframe because it stops some links on my site from working. I've tried positioning the js just after the body tag but it still doesn't work.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=458816400855910";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The twitter widget may be interfering with it but only the Facebook widget seems to be affected.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the BODY tag?!

Make it at the very end, i.e.

```
<html>
<body>

    Place the stuff here, between the body tag!

</body>
<!-- NOT HERE, not AFTER! -->
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say after the start of the body tag. I want to move it closer to where I have it on my site but I'm leaving at the start until I get it working.

If it helps here is the code used to place the Like Box

    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/SBITBrisbane?fref=ts" data-width="300" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=458816400855910";
```

to

```
js.src = "**https:**//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=458816400855910";
```